# With Carrierwave, I want to resize photos to different sizes depending on the type of photo uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, rmagick, carrierwave

I have a User model and a Post model. A user's photo will be resized to a small thumbnail, and a post's photo will be resized to a large thumbnail.

```
version :smallThumb do
     process :resize_to_fill => [100, 100]
   end

   version :largeThumb do
     process :resize_to_fill => [200, 200]
   end
```

How do I tell carrierwave which size to choose for an uploaded photo? Will it resize to both small and large for all uploads?

Answer (score 3):

You can create 2 separate uploader models. Would look something like this:

profile_uploader.rb

```
class ProfileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [200, 200]
  end

end
```

atached_uploader.rb

```
class AttachedUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [100, 100]
  end

end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :profile, ProfileUploader

end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :attached, AttachedUploader

end
```